# find an example of a function which satisfies certain properties

Tags: calculus

Is there any Method for solving this kind of question:

$f(x)$ is defined and differentiable on every point and the derivative of $f(x)$ fails to be differentiable at exactly two points. Give an example of $f(x)$.

Comment: Go the other way around: start with a candidate derivative and integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints

- Take a function $f$ which is equal to $0$ for $x<0$ and to a polynomial function of lowest degree possible for $x \ge 0$.
- Those should be chosen in order that the function is continuous, differentiable at any point and that the derivative of $f$ fails to be differentiable at $0$.
- Then what do you think of $g(x)=f(x+1)+f(x)$?

And for the fun... A much harder question. What do you think of finding a function having those properties for an infinite number of points?